# Planification vs Actual Entities in database modeling

Tags: database, data-modeling, modeling

I've been working on several projects lately as part of a job as developer for small startups and I've come across this question several times by now. What to do when you have an entity that consists of a planification and later the actual thing?

As an example let's think of a company wanting to have a record of all their security drills. Of course this means that someone will make a planification for a drill, perhaps choose a date and time for it and the people that will partake in it. This accounts for the planification of the entity. After a while the drill actually happens, and so we want to have a record of the actual date and time of the occurrence (to keep it simple, let's assume the people in the planification are always the same as the actual participants).

Example:

[image: ERM of the Drill as separate entities]

[image: ERM of the Drill as a single entity]

I've seen this same situation in lots of other practical examples, training planning and actual training, scheduled maintenance and actual maintenance, estimated budget and actual fees, etc. Sometimes we've solved this issues by using boolean attributes such as "planned", "done", "completed" or "approved" in one entity. Other times we used separate entities, but haven't quite reached a consensus of what is the better option.

What do you think would be the best option for this kind of problem? A PlanificationEntity and an actual Entity? Just a boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on what is being planned, so there is no single answer.

In your case, drills seem to accumulate information over time and to change state.  There seems to be a separate drill every time you do planning and only that drill is executed.  You might want to keep only the current state, but I would generally want to keep transition tables to know when something happens.

A variation might be a class or a training, where there is a standard training.  That might be stored as an entity (say in `trainings`).  You would then have a `training_schedule` table, which could have past and future dates -- as well as a unique id.  Then the participants would be linked to the `training_schedule`.

Yet another variation is a budget versus actuals.  In this case, the budget is in many ways its own entity, that you want to name and keep over time.  The actuals accumulate and you want to compare them.  That would be a different data model, because there can be multiple budgets active at the same time (the original one for the year and the updated budget based on actuals that have already happened).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I see, even when is just a transition it is recommended to have a separate entity for that? I think the main question is related to the fact that all the examples have a 1 to 1 relation, and at the time of creating database tables they "could" become a single table. Might not be the best approach, tough. As I understood from your answer it's still beter to have them as separate entities.

Comment: @JuanDrago . . . No, probably not.  You might want a transition table of some sort to record state changes.  Or to have multiple date/times to indicate when the states changed in a single record.  It depends on how "fixed" the dates are and whether a drill could return to an earlier state.

Answer (score 0):

Planification entities should be called configuration entities. Like drillConfiguration and drill. DrillConfiguration can have drill date and time and any other attributes. While drill is the actual drill with a foreign key attribute for drillconfiguration. That’s my two cents

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So in this case Drill would have actualDate (or just date) and DrillConfiguration would have the planned date?

Comment: Drill will have actualDate and drillConfiguration will have planned/expectedDate yes.